# Get console output of adb command from python subprocces

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, adb

```
import subprocess

while True:
    subprocess.call(input("> "), shell=True)
```

let's say when I run `adb shell settings get system volume_music_speaker`, how can I get the console output and store it, which let's say, it's max volume so the return value would be 14. I have already tried

```
while True:
    a = subprocess.call(input("> "), shell=True)
    print(a)
```

but I always get 0. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE

```
with subprocess.Popen(input("> "),
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
) as your_process:
    output, err = your_process.communicate()
```

Comment: Thanks, it  works, I also figured out this which works but your solution is better:
while True:
    command = input("> ")

     output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
     print("Output:", output)